# Are these conditions regarding products of consecutive terms in a sequence of positive numbers equivalent?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, operator-theory

Assume $w_n$ is a bounded (weight) sequence of positive numbers. We want to consider products of consecutive terms in this sequence. For $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$, define $M_i^j = w_i w_{i+1}\cdots w_{i+j-1}$; that is to say, $M_i$ is the product of $j$ terms, starting with the $i$th term. Consider the following three statements concerning the sequence $w_n$.

\begin{align*}
    P: & \sup_{n\geq 1} M_1^n = \infty  \hskip .2in \text{ and } \hskip .2in \inf_{n,i\geq 1} M_i^n >0 \\[0.2in]
    Q: & \inf_{n} w_n>0, \hskip .2in \text{ and } \hskip .2in \exists \text{ increasing } (n_k) \text{ s.t. } \lim_{k\to \infty} M_1^{n_k} = \infty \text{ and } \limsup_{k\to \infty} \left(\inf_{i\geq 1} M_i^{n_k}\right) >0\\[0.2in]
    R: & \inf_{n} w_n>0, \hskip .2in \text{  and  } \hskip .2in \sup_{n\geq 1} M_1^n = \infty,  \hskip .2in \text{  and  } \hskip .2in \limsup_{n\to \infty} \left(\inf_{i\geq 1} M_i^n \right)>0\\[0.2in]
\end{align*}

It's not terribly difficult to prove $P\implies Q \implies R$. My question is: must $R\implies Q$?

Some undergraduates and I proved $Q \nRightarrow P$ by coming up with a sequence $w_n$ which has property $Q$ but not property $P$. Here is such an example, minus a few details. Consider the sequence $w_n$ constructed in blocks $b_n$ given by
\begin{align*}
    \underbrace{2}_{b_1} \underbrace{ \frac 12}_{b_2} \underbrace{22 }_{b_3} \underbrace{ \frac 12 1111 \frac 12}_{b_4} \underbrace{222}_{b_5}  \underbrace{  \frac 12 1111111111 \frac 12 1111111111 \frac 12}_{b_6} \underbrace{2222}_{b_7} \underbrace{ \frac 12 1\cdots 1 \frac 12 1 \cdots}_{b_8} 
\end{align*}

Block $b_{2n-1}$ has $n$ 2's in it. Block $b_{2n}$ has $n$ $\frac 12$'s in it, and between any pair of $\frac 12$'s in $b_{2n}$, there are as many 1's as the total number of terms in all the previously appearing blocks. Let $|b_n|$ denote the length of block $b_n$. Then for $n_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k} |b_{2k-1}|$, the number $M_1^{n_k}$ represents the product of all the weights in the first $2k-1$ blocks, which we have arranged to equal $2^k$. One could then go on to show that there are enough 1's in the odd blocks to ensure $M_i^{n_k} \geq \frac 12$ for any $i$, and hence $Q$ is satisfied. But if we multiply all the weights in block $b_{2k}$, we get $2^{-k}$, so that $P$ is not satisfied.

The conditions $P, Q,$ and $R$ are related to (newly introduced) dynamical properties that a weighted backward shift operator on $c_0$ could have; the interested reader can check out [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.02073), although this post is more related to ongoing work [found here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.02899). I'm not confident those resources are useful, but they do provide the origin, context, and motivation for our question.

We are looking for any insight into whether or not $R\implies Q$ is true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, $R$ does not yield $Q$.

Denote $f(n)=\log M_1^n$, then $R$ reads as

(i) $f(n+1)-f(n)$ is bounded from below;

(ii) $\sup f=+\infty$;

(iii) there exists a sequence $n_1<n_2<\ldots$ and a constant $C$ such that $f(x+n_i)-f(x)\geqslant -C$ for all positive integer $n$.

And $Q$ asks whether the sequence in (iii) may be chosen so that $\lim f(n_i)=+\infty$.

For a binary positive integer $x=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \varepsilon_j 2^j$, $\varepsilon_j\in \{0,1\}$ put $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \varepsilon_j$.

Then (i) and (iii) for $n_i=2^i$ follows from the fact that when you add a power of 2 to a positive integer, several consecutive 1's in its binary expansion become equal to 0, and also one 0 becomes 1. This does not affect an alternating sum of binary digits too much. (ii) is obvious.

But since $f(2x)=-f(x)$, any sequence satisfying $f(n_i)\to +\infty$ also satisfy $f(2n_i)-f(n_i)=-2f(n_i)\to -\infty$, so such sequence does not satisfy (iii).